# Custom Usercontrol in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I am designing a user control in ASP.NET where in i have a Textbox and onfoucus javascript event i am showing a checkbox list below and onBlur event i am hiding the checkbox list control

Now the problem is when i focus the textbox the Checkbox is visible and when i try to go and check the items it is getting hidden as onBlur event is called.

How can i avoid this any other way for this basically like a dropdown list....

Answer (score 1):

Don't hide it in the `onblur` event.

Imitate what a real dropdown list does: it only goes away when either [a] you click an item in the list [b] some other page element is clicked.

Comment: do we have onclick javascript event for ascx (user control)??

Answer (score 0):

Try hiding the checkbox on the click event (of checkbox).